# Javascript - return array of values that totals next number up

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to work out the best way to achieve the following:

A score might require a total of 25 'items' **AS A MINIMUM**

currently that person might have 15.8 'items'

I have a number of items required to reach that score (9.2)

So to get that score the minimum a person must have is 10 'items' in x weeks (to be 25.8 and over the 25 threshold).

Assuming they have 4 weeks to do it that gives 2.5 needed per week.

What I am struggling with is how to output an array of 'whole items' that will make 10.

e.g.

```
2
3
2
3
```

I want the items to be as evenly distributed as possible.

so

```
1
2
3
4
```

would be useless

I am just trying to work out the best way to do this.

I was thinking of:
finding nearest whole number ROUNDED UP (3 in this example)
Then outputting that number
Then on the next pass gathering the 'remainder' (-0.5) and then rounding the number.

But it doesn't quite work for all cases.

Can anyone help me get my head around it without writing hundreds of lines of code.

As a further example say 17 were needed in 5 weeks that would be

```
4
3
3
4
3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: the code is long and takes away from what I am asking - it is basically a loop that counts remainders as it goes and then when remainders are less than -0.5 it adds +1 to the required number

Comment: You might get good results more simply by calculating the amount still needed, dividing it by the weeks remaining, adding that to the next week, then repeating. So you calculate the remaining needed for *each week* and build as you go. I think that might give you decent balance without managing a lot of state and reshuffling. Untested, my be crazy...

Comment: thanks for suggestion - will have a fiddle and see if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it some way like this:

```
function myFunction(total, weeks) {
    var n = 0;
    var temp = 0;
    var arr = [];
    while (n < total) {
        temp = n;
        n += total / weeks;
        arr.push(Math.floor(n) - Math.floor(temp));
    }
    return arr;
}
myFunction(10, 4); //[2, 3, 2, 3]
myFunction(17, 5); //[3, 3, 4, 3, 4]
```

In this code, `total / weeks` will be the average number you'll want to add to `n` to get from `0` to `total` in exactly `weeks` iterations.

Now the difference between the original value of `n` (which is stored in `temp`) and the new value of `n` is pushed to the array. That will give you the rounded numbers you'll need to add up to the entered `total`.

Comment: Perfect - just what I was looking for - added it to my code snippet library too as it is nice and succinct. Thanks Joey